# Confirmation Box on specific button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need a confirmation box to pop up when a user hits a Save button on my webpage. I currently have a confirm box showing up whenever a user hits ANY button. I need it strictly for the one. The button I need it linked to is called btnsavesurvey.

Here is my current code in the page_load:

```
Dim message As String = "Do you want to complete survey?"

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    sb.Append("return confirm('")

    sb.Append(message)

    sb.Append("');")

    ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnsavesurvey').click(function(){
      var r = confirm("Your message");
      if (r == true) {
         alert("You pressed OK!");
          // Do something when the user pressed ok
      } else {
          alert("You pressed Cancel!");
          // Do something when the user pressed cancel
      };

 });
```

If your btns id is btnsavesurvey if its class is btnsavesurvey than use .btnsavesurvey

Comment: Sven, could I get more clarification on that answer? Also, I need to convert what you sent as VB instead of C#. Thanks.

Comment: Your using asp right ? you can use <script>the code i posted </script> in your views to run javascript.

Comment: @JonVisconti updated the answer so you know where to put the action to handle the decision